# Transform a Single of an object to a Single of an inner field of that same object in RxJava

Tags: java, mongodb, java-8, rx-java2, micronaut

I have a User model which embed an Caracteristic model

```
public class User {
    private List<Caracteristic> cracteristics;
}
```

Using `Flowable` and `rxJava` i want to get a list of all Caracteristics of all users i.e. to transform a `Single<List<User>>` to `Single<List<Caracteristics>>`

```
@Controller("cars")
 public class CaracteristicController() {

     public Single<List<User> list() {
          return Flowable.fromPublisher(
                   getCollection().find(exists("caracteristics")))
                   .toList();
     }

     private MongoCollection<User> getCollection() {
         return dbClient
            .getDatabase(dbConfiguration.getDatabaseName())
            .getCollection(dbConfiguration.getCollectionName(), User.class);
     }

 }
```

User model is a document in a MongoDB database

```
{
  "name" : "name",
  "caracteristics" : [
    {
    "desc" : "carac 1",
    "ref" : "ROO12"
  },
  {
    "desc" : "carac 2",
    "ref" : "ROO14"
  }]
}
```

I don't know how to manipulate the `Flowable` or the `Single` to return a list of `Caracteristic` objects instead of users.

Comment: Use the map operator. http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#map-io.reactivex.functions.Function-

Comment: Actually i tried to but didn't work as expected. You think of using it after collecting the Single<List<User>> or after. I concise small example would be of great help ? Knowing Also that using map basically will return a List of Lists which i don't want. flatMap could help but don't know how to manipulate it in context of reactive streams

Comment: Using map() won't return a Single<List<List>> is you pass a lambda that transforms the List<User> into a List<Characteristics>. So the problem is: how to do that? You can use a loop, or a stream: `.map(users -> users.stream().flatMap(u -> u.getCharacteristics.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList()))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get a list of all Characteristics of all users you can achieve it like this:

```
Single<List<User>> users = ...;
Single<List<Characteristics>> characteristics = users
    .flatMapObservable(Observable::fromIterable)
    .flatMapIterable(user -> user.characteristics)
    .toList();
```

Comment: @Hassam care to explain how this solved your problem that could not be solved by my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `flatMapIterable` operator to merge the list of characteristics from all user objects into a `Single`.

```
public Single<List<Characteristic>> list() {
  return Flowable.fromPublisher(getCollection().find(exists("caracteristics")))
    .flatMapIterable((user) -> user.characteristics)
    .toList();
}

private MongoCollection<User> getCollection() {
  return MongoClients.create()
    .getDatabase("db")
    .getCollection("collection", User.class);
}
```

Comment: As a user stores a List of Charcteristic .map((user) -> user.characteristics) would return a List<List<Characteristics>> that not what i wanted